# Поле Input + выпадающий список

Tags: javascript

Есть поле *Input*, в которое вводится текст, и, в зависимости от введенного текста, выдается выпадающий список.

Примерно так это должно выглядеть:

[image: изображение]

Как это реализовать?

Comment: Пожалуйста, дайте больше информации. Пример вводимого текста и соответствующего списка. Что должно произойти, если введенный текст не имеет никаких соответствующих жлементов в спике и т.д.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как я понял вам нужна идея реализации, а не сам код (если сам код то вопрос стоит закрыть - это работа за автора).
Идея примерно следующая:

1. Выпадающий список - это элемент `select`.
2. Ставим обработчики событий на элемент `input`. Я думаю `keypress` как минимум (нажатие клавиши), может быть `change` (зависит, что нужно) и прочие события, чтобы отслеживать изменение текста.
3. Когда в поле `input` текст, который нам нужен (вам виднее), а он проверяется при каждом изменении, то надо javascript'ом изменить `select`, а именно добавить/удалить элементы `option`, которые отвечают за набор вариантов в выпадающем списке.

Вообщем-то это все. Если нужны какие-то уточнения, то пишите в комментариях.

UPD: Заметил у вас кнопку `GO to`. Если на нее надо нажимать чтобы изменить выпадающий список, то обработчики событий изменения текста вообще и не нужны